# SVM caret error: "Std. deviations could not be computed for... missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

I am trying to run this code for SVM in caret with a stratified cross-validation but I get this error:"Std. deviations could not be computed for: diff1, diff2, diff3, diff4, diff5, diff6,...model fit failed for Resample01: sigma=0.000, C=0.010 Error in if (any(co)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

"diff1, diff2, diff3, diff4, diff5, diff6,..." are the quantitative variables used for the prediction of a factor variable with 2 levels

```
   set.seed(1) 
    folds<-createFolds(file_test$y,k=10,list=FALSE) # statified folds for cross-validation 
    ctrl<-trainControl(method="repeatedcv",index=folds,classProbs = TRUE,summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
    grid_radial <- expand.grid(
      sigma = c(0,0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.075, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75,0.9),
     C = c(0.01,0.025,0.05,0.075,0.1,0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1))
    SVMrad<-train(y ~., data=file_test,
                  method="svmRadial", # SVM algorithm
                  tuneGrid = grid_radial, 
                  trControl=ctrl, 
                  preProc=c("center","scale"), 
                  metric="ROC")
```

I checked the 'file_test' but there are no missing values.

I hope you can help me fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong: I had to use the option "list=TRUE" in the createFolds function:

```
folds<-createFolds(file_test$y,k=10,list=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

is y a `factor`? for example is y is a vector of 1s and 0s you will need to run

```
file_test$y <- as.factor(ifelse(y==1, "one","zero"))
```

Comment: Yes it is a factor and I already did what you suggest, but I still have the error.

Comment: @Pauline Did you one hot encode? You cant have any factors or dates as predictor variables with SVM.

Comment: All my predictor variables (diff1-diff538) are numeric, these are mid-infrared wavelengths. And the y is a factor with two levels (pregnant - open)